# iis express 7.5 roaming profile visual studio 2010 sp1

Tags: iis-express

Unless I redirect the My Documents folder to a local copy IIS Express fails to start with the following error message:
Filename: redirection.config
Error: Cannot read configuration file

This happens when starting a new web project from studio or even is I just double click on the iisexpress.exe file.

Any way around this or must I continue to redirec the My Documents folder

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. I am using VMWare Fusion, so my PC is a virtual machine, and the My Documents folder is mapped to the Documents folder on the Mac side. In other words, it is as if it were on a network drive.

The bug has been reported here:
http://connect.microsoft.com/webmatrix/feedback/details/637342/iis-express-doesnt-run-when-my-documents-is-on-a-root-drive#details

but not solution is provided. If we could only find where to set the IIS Express configuration files path...

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using old version of IIS Express. Un-install your current IIS Exprss and install latest refresh release from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=abc59783-89de-4adc-b770-0a720bb21deb

Let us know if this does not solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.... I downloaded and re-installed and this did not not fix the problem. I've tried running iisexpress.exe from its folder and also starting new project in vs2010 sp1. Same results. What else can be done.

Comment: Delete/rename %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress folder and try again.

Comment: Deleting the folder and running iisexpress.exe does recreate it, but unfortunately it does not fix the proble. I've installed WebMatrix and this does start new projects I create in web matrix, but not existing folders with websites.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem when the organisation I worked for changed the network drive where they've mapped my My Documents folder (along with a bunch of others). It used to be on \machine1\myusername$ and was moved to \someothermachine\myusername$.

When I tried to fire up iisexpress in a console window from "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>" via a VS command prompt, it came back with

`An error occurred while reading configuration information. Make sure that the configuration file \\machine1\myusername$\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config exists, it is accessible, and contains valid configuration information.`

Their script didn't bother to zip through the registry and update the pointers from the old "home" to the new one. So I ended up with missing files, duplicates in some cases, and rude messages along the lines of "this file is currently not available for use on this computer".

To fix it, I did the following:

1. Located the root/base of my new "My documents" folder (now `\\someothermachine\myusername$`)
2. Did a (manual, via regedit) registry search for keys, values and data for `\\machine1\myusername$\` and replaced it with the new version. This took a while, there were about 40-50 replacements.
3. Rebooted.

I was then able to fire up iisexpress again, from the same console window. It re-registered the standard base website, and it's all working again.

I hope this helps someone else!